# Deriving the subsolution table for LCS from the brute force solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm working on the LCS problem using dynamic programming. I'm having trouble deriving the DP solution myself without looking at the solution.

I currently reason that given two strings, P and Q:

- We can enumerate through all subsequences of P, which is of size `2^n`.
- We can also enumerate through all subsequences of Q, which is of size `2^m`.

So, if we want to check for shared subsequences, the run time would be `O(2^n * 2^m)` or `O(2^(n+m))`.

I don't understand how we can go from this brute force solution to the dynamic programming solution. What's the logic for deriving the subsolution table?

I just don't understand how we can jump straight to the subsolution table for DP from this point. What's the logic for doing that?

I understand that we need to identify overlapping subsolutions. But I can't find a good explanation for identifying this then going onto the subsolution table.

Let me know if this question makes sense.

Comment: Its very very easy, once you understand the basics.

Comment: Yeah, everyone tells that to me, I can't understand it to be honest. (Without looking at the solution). I'm trying to derive this entirely from scratch and I feel like a buffoon.

Comment: So you did not understand my answer??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea that creates the magic for this algorithm.

Consider 2 strings `S1` and `S2`,

```
S1 = c1,c2,c3,........cm, length = m
```

and

```
S2 = b1,b2,b3,........bn, length = n
```

Say you have a function `LCS(arg1,arg2)`, where

```
arg1 = S1,m , string S1 of length of m
```

and

arg2 = S2,n , string S2 of length of n

and `LCS(arg1,arg2)` will give us the length of longest common subsequence for the 2 arguments.

Now suppose that the last character of both strings is same.

```
bn = cm
```

And suppose **no other two charcters is same**. This  means that:

```
LCS(arg1,arg2) = 1(last character) + 0(remaining strings)
```

Now if you have understood the above equation, its clear that if instead of no other two characters matching we do have something matching(**in the remaining strings**) then:

```
LCS(arg1,arg2) = 1(last character) + LCS(arg1 - cm,arg2 - bn)(Remaining strings)
```

But if **last two chars do not match**, then definitely **we have to consider the second last 2 characters** in each string and thats why we have the following when the **last 2 characters does not match**:

```
LCS(arg1,arg2) = max(LCS(arg1 - cm,arg2) , LCS(arg1 ,arg2 - bn))
```

Comment: I don't understand this line: `LCS(arg1,arg2) = 1(last character) + 0(remaining strings)`

1 is a function of last character?

Comment: Or do you mean that LCS(arg1,arg2) = 1?

Comment: What does `1(last character)` mean?

Comment: Dude i don't get it

Comment: @echo It means  LCS(arg1,arg2) = 1.

Comment: @echo Because only last 2 characters match.

Comment: I get it. We're essentially processing the two strings simultaneously and popping off the last character if it contributes to the optimal subsequence. And we're considering all popping patterns that are possible. Would you say that's true?

Comment: I find it weird how dynamic programming problems have each different tables. Like this table is pivoted on N and M. But some are pivoted on other aspects. From what I understand: this is based on how you identify the overlapping subproblems. Right?